# DSC add user in local group

Tags: powershell, dsc

In DSC configuration i shoud add local user in group, but before that how i can check if user exists or not, and only after that add in group

```
User User { 
            Ensure   = "Present"  # To ensure the user account does not exist, set Ensure to "Absent" 
            UserName = "user" 
        } 
 
        Group AdminGroup { 
            GroupName        = "AdminGroup" 
            DependsOn        = "[User]user" 
            MembersToInclude = "user" 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the strong point in using DSC. It will just check the state of the named resource. If the state is as specified (in this case present), it will do nothing. If it is not in the desired state (in this case absent) , dsc will look to make sure the resource is added. By specifying DependsOn in the group resource, you can be sure that the user resource will be checked first.

So no need to change the code :)

Answer (score 0):

DSC will automatically check to see if the desired state exists and adjust as needed.